# GoogleMap in Drawer flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

I would like to limit the size of the map to a part of the drawer and to show the current location marked on the map. This way it stays on the whole drawer and only shows the location when I press the location symbol...

```
 Widget _buildDrawer(BuildContext context) {
          return Drawer(
              child: Flex(
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
              Expanded(
              child:GoogleMap(
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              initialCameraPosition: _currentPosition,
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                _controller.complete(controller);
              },
            ))]));
  }
```

...

```
currentPosition = CameraPosition(
        bearing: 192.8334901395799,
        target: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        tilt: 59.440717697143555,
        zoom: 19.151926040649414);
```

Tried too: but is in full again

```
Drawer(
              child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.10,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.10,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                    flex: 70,
                    child: GoogleMap(
               mapType: MapType.hybrid,
               mapToolbarEnabled: false,
               zoomControlsEnabled: false,
               myLocationEnabled: true,
              initialCameraPosition: _currentPosition,
               onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
                 _controller.complete(controller);
               },
          ),
          )])))
```

Answer (score 0):

child: Column(children: [GoogleMap()])

this way you can store multiple widgets within the draw without having the map take up the entire widget.

You have to options as far as styling the GoogleMap() widget

1. You can change the style within the google map widget
   2)You can style the parent widget which holds the GooggleMap()

for column this would be => Column(mainaxisalignmen: mainaxisalignment.center etc.

column is not the only widget you have to use, any widget that takes children is a good choice for being the child of the drawer